# Resolving a `Manifest` for a type with a type member

Tags: scala, type-members

I am having trouble resolving a `scala.reflect.Manifest` for a type with a type member.

For example,

```
import scala.reflect.Manifest

trait Foo {
  type T
}

trait Bar[T]

object Main extends App {

  val barM: Manifest[Bar[Int]] =
    implicitly[Manifest[Bar[Int]]]

  val fooM: Manifest[Foo{type T = Int}] =
    implicitly[Manifest[Foo{type T = Int}]]

}
```

The above code does not compile, giving the following error.

```
Foo.scala:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.reflect.Manifest[Foo]
 required: scala.reflect.Manifest[Foo{type T = Int}]
Note: Foo >: Foo{type T = Int}, but trait Manifest is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: Foo{type T = Int}`. (SLS 3.2.10)
    implicitly[Manifest[Foo{type T = Int}]]
              ^
one error found
```

But the `barM` declaration works just fine.

I am aware that type members are not quite type parameters, but I am definitely not up on all the subtleties.

How can one go about resolving a `Manifest` for a type with a *concrete* type member?

Comment: Looks like it might be related to this, http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/6550.

Answer (score 1):

Structural types are not supported by `Manifest`. [SI-4252](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4252) (`Manifest` of structural types) is labelled as "won't fix", and it is recommended that you use `TypeTag` instead. `Manifest` is also likely to be deprecated soon.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

scala> implicitly[TypeTag[Foo { type T = Int} ]]
res18: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Foo{type T = Int}] = TypeTag[Foo{type T = Int}]
```

You might also be able to work around this with a type alias, but it's hard to tell without a use-case.

```
scala> type FooAux[T] = Foo { type T }
defined type alias FooAux

// Compiles, but is it useful?
scala> implicitly[Manifest[FooAux[Int]]]
res19: scala.reflect.Manifest[FooAux[Int]] = Foo
```

Comment: I thought your answer was correct, but now I am not sure. This *isn't* a structural type. While the syntax is similar, structural types emit reflective calls to verify that something is correct, while this is just plain old type members, no reflective calls.

Comment: I had already attempted the type alias solution. Alas it does not work as the compiler still gets upset about the variance of the type member.